# General question about convergence of complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

We say that $ \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}z_{k} $ converge if the sequence $ s_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}z_{k} $ converge. And we say that $ s_n $ converge to a complex number $ s $ if $ |s_{n}-s|\to0 $.

I wonder if this definition equivalent to say that $  \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}z_{k} $ converge if and only if both $ \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\text{Re}(z_{k}) $  and $ \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\text{Im}(z_{k}) $ converge.

If the answer is yes, I have a follow up question:

I assume that if both $ \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}\text{|Re}(z_{k})|\thinspace\thinspace,\thinspace\thinspace\underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}|\text{Im}(z_{k})| $ converge, we can conclude that $ \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}z_{k}$ converge absolutely, but if we know that one of those series does not converge absolutely, can we conclude for sure that $ \underset{k=1}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}z_{k} $ does not converge absolutely?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, these are all true.  One cautionary note: it’s common in complex analysis to write $s_n \to \infty$ to mean that $|s_n| \to +\infty$.  In that case it’s entirely possible for $s_n \to \infty$ at the same time that $\Re(s_n)$ converges to, say, $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is affirmative, and you will find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675082/proving-convergence-of-real-and-imaginary-parts).

Concerning the other question, suppose that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname{Re}(z_n)$ does not converge absolutely. That is, that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\bigl|\operatorname{Re}(z_n)\bigr|$ diverges. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|z_n|$ diverges too, since, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $\bigl|\operatorname{Re}(z_n)\bigr|\leqslant|z_n|$. The situation in which the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname{Im}(z_n)$ does not converge absolutely is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Indeed, you have
$$|\mathrm{Re}(z_k)| \leq |z_k| \quad \text{and} \quad |\mathrm{Im}(z_k)| \leq |z_k| $$

so if $\sum z_k$ converges absolutely, then so do $\sum \mathrm{Re}(z_k)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(z_k)$.